# Style not getting applied from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to programmatically assign Style through code-behind but it doesn't seem to be working...I don't see MyIcon appearing in the grid column.
When debugging, I see that the value of sBase is null.
What am I missing here please?

```
  <Window.Resources>  
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageStatusStyle">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/MyIcon.ico"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.ShowImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>




<grid:MyDevXpfGrid x:Name="gridResult" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDetails}" Height="Auto"  Width="Auto" MaxHeight="1000" 
                                       AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" AutoGeneratingColumn="gridResult_AutoGeneratingColumn"  Margin="0">
```

MyWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void gridResult_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.AutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayInfo displayInfo = e.Column.Tag as DisplayInfo;
    if (e.Column.ActualColumnChooserHeaderCaption.ToString()  == "MyColumn")
    {
        e.Column.CellTemplate = GetImageDataTemplate();
    }
}

private static DataTemplate GetImageDataTemplate()
{
    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Image));

    Style sBase = Application.Current.Resources["ImageStatusStyle"] as Style;
    Style sNew = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Image), sBase);

    factory.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.StyleProperty, sNew);

    template.VisualTree = factory;

    return template;
}
```

Note, that if I apply the same style from within xaml code, its working fine and I can see MyIcon appearing in the grid column....for e.g.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource ImageStatusStyle}"  />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use DataTemplate as a Resource againt use just your style? You could apply directly `e.Column.CellTemplate=Application.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate`

Comment: Sorry @KelvnRisso, didn't get that..where and how do I define MyDataTemplate?thanks

Comment: You can create another `ResourceDictionary` and put your DataTemplate there. Like this: `<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <Image ... />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>`

Comment: @KelvynRisso: I added DataTemplate under ResourceDictionary but but now I get value for following as null: Application.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

Comment: You trying to access to Application scope resources, and in your xaml you put desired resource to Window scope...

Comment: @Sam, you need to add your ResourceDictionary to your App.xaml.

Comment: @KelvnRisso, I had tried that.I still get the same error.

Comment: @Sam, Can you share your ResourceDictionary and the caller to it?